# ArcGIS - Locate features along routes returning double results?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, line, route

I am using locate features long routes using a points layer and a routed polyline network.

[image]

Each point has a unique ID. My end goal is to determine is a point is to the left or right of the line.

However my locate features along routes output is returning the point (field UNIQ) as being on both side of the line? Each row has exactly the same measure as the one above it and the same distance (but negative). Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Your route appears to branch, which means It is not a simple route.  So are you sure the route built with unique measures at every vertex?  Also, are you sure no geometry in the route is doubled in both directions?  It would help to show the set up of the Locate Features Along Route tool so we can see if that has any effect.  Show the locations created by making your table into a route event layer with a side offset and select the two duplicate events to show where the events fall relative to the original point.   I know curves create duplicate events, but they normally fall on the same side.

Comment: Each individual polygon centrepoint has a unique ID (FW0 is highlighted). 

https://i.gyazo.com/bd6eceeff63a80ace88ec85e825ad5b8.png

As you can see this is only on the right of the line so therefor the +3.301 distance is correct

https://i.gyazo.com/a23d55a30112ff4722cef7dc5cb52084.png

I created the routes using a two field methods, 0 and digitised polyline length. There is no doubling over of geometry.

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using?  I have not seen this behavior with 10.3.1 or with previous versions that I can recall.  Curves do create more than one event on the interior curve side, but that does not appear to apply to your example and the two events would have the same side distance if it did.  Please show or describe all the settings you used when you ran the Locate Features Along Route tool.

Comment: I'm on 10.2.1. 

Route Identifier Field: Unique reference assigned to each individual polyline
Measure Source: TWO_FIELDS
One populated with '0' and the other populated with the digitised length

Locate features along routes:
Input features: point layer displayed earlier
Input route features: routed polyline created earlier
Search radius: 20m
Output event table: .dbf

Comment: Edit the Sketch of the example route just to make sure the XYM coordinates all make sense and that the route is a single-part simple route.  A screen shot of that would be nice.  I cannot reproduce the behavior you are seeing with 10.3.1 and I used this tool many times with version 10.2.1 and did not see this behavior.  Try changing the Use M Direction Offsetting option and possibly the Keep Only Closest Route Location option to see if they produce a different effect.  You may have to contact Esri tech support to have them see if there is any bug like this logged.

Comment: Very frustrating to say the least... This makes me want to go back to an earlier version of ArcGIS when this issue was not an occurrence (10.1). I knew this was an issue in ~10.2 and I thought it was resolved in 10.3; however, for the first time I am receiving duplicates when I run this tool. I have the basic license so I cannot use the delete identical tool to resolve the issue, but why should I need an advanced license to fix an issue created by ESRI's ArcGIS software. Has ESRI resolved this in 10.4 or is there a service pack fixing the issue in 10.3? I found that the dissolve tool in absenc

Answer (score -1):

That is a [known bug](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/85457), use the [Delete Identical](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm) to remove them.

Comment: Would this take into account that some are plus and minus offsets? I need to know which out of the plus or minus offset is correct.